# Angular CLI Material Table DataSource

Tags: angular, command-line-interface, datasource

I have a coding project that I am working on and I used the Angular CLI to do a new Data Table. I have had a lot of trouble getting my API data to display.

I finally managed to get my data to display, but only if I key into the dataSource, which in turn breaks all my pagination and sorting.

If someone could help me out, I have been trying to debug myself, but after way too many hours I am just simply going in circles.

API Service

```
  getAllUsers(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<any>('http://localhost:3000/users');
  }
```

Datasource.ts

```
export class UserTableDataSource extends DataSource<UserTableItem> {
  data: UserTableItem[] = EXAMPLE_DATA;
  paginator: MatPaginator;
  sort: MatSort;


  constructor(private api: ApiService) {
    super()
    this.api.getUserAll().subscribe(result => this.data = result)
  }
```

Component.ts

```
export class UserTableComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnInit {
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
  @ViewChild(MatTable) table: MatTable<UserTableItem>;
  dataSource: UserTableDataSource;
  dataTest;
  userId;
  allDem;

  constructor(private api: ApiService,  private route: ActivatedRoute){}

  /** Columns displayed in the table. Columns IDs can be added, removed, or reordered. */
  displayedColumns = ['id', 'name', 'username', 'email', 'actions'];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataSource = new UserTableDataSource(this.api);
    console.log(this.dataSource)
  }
```

HTML file

```
  <table mat-table class="full-width-table" [dataSource]="dataSource.data"  matSort aria-label="Elements">
```

Anyone that can help me refactor this code so that I can access my data without `dataSource.data` on the HTML file, I will be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Why not setup dataSource by this
`this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.api);`?
Maybe u can try this